# How do I change my email address?

Tags: support, user-accounts

I recently got a new email address, and I was wondering how do update my profile and change my old email to my new email for my account?

I have tried many things like click on my email but it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you simply click the 'edit' button on your profile page, which is up near the privileges & preferences menu items:

[image: Picture highlighting the edit button]

Comment: Thanks robotnik you are awesome!